# Get nearest value for each hour in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

these values are in the table:

```
DateTime            Value
05.02.2020 10:40:00 3,9990
05.02.2020 12:11:32 4,0090
05.02.2020 12:14:36 4,0170
05.02.2020 12:15:16 4,0280
05.02.2020 12:16:20 4,0380
05.02.2020 12:17:28 4,0400
05.02.2020 22:14:57 4,0480
```

I need a query which gives me the value for the nearest hour and fill the values with zero if there is no entry for the hour. For example for the timespan hours 11 - 22:

```
DateTime            Value
05.02.2020 11:00:00 3,9990 //value 10:40 is nearest value to 11:00
05.02.2020 12:00:00 4,0090
05.02.2020 13:00:00 0,0000
05.02.2020 14:00:00 0,0000
05.02.2020 15:00:00 0,0000
...
05.02.2020 22:00:00 4,0480
```

I have a query to get the closest value to a given hour but I'm not able to change it to get the result I need:

```
select top 1 DateTime, Value
  from (select t.*,
  abs(datediff(second,'2020-02-20 11:00:00.0000000',DateTime)) df
  from MyTable t
  WHERE TagName = 'Criteria' 
  AND DateTime > '2020-02-20 00:00:00.000'
  AND DateTime < '2020-02-20 22:00:00.000'
  ) x
  order by df
```

Comment: Tag you question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  You need to generate the hours.  This can use a calendar table, numbers table, or something similar.  Here, I'll use a recursive CTE to generate the hours.

Then, I think that a lateral join (`outer apply`) is the best approach.  In this case, the lateral join is just like a correlated subquery:

```
with hours as (
      select convert(datetime, '2020-02-05 10:00:00') as hh,
             convert(datetime, '2020-02-05 22:00:00') as hhmax
      union all
      select dateadd(hour, 1, hh), hhmax
      from hours
      where hh < hhmax
     )
select h.hh, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from hours h outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where t.datetime >= h.hh and
            t.datetime < dateadd(hour, 1, h.hh)
      order by t.datetime asc
     ) t;
```

Comment: It gives me the error: `Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Comment: @Katz . . . Just added the `hhmax` to the second query.